# Is there anyway to send a Model to the server(controler action method) when using jqGrid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have an Asp.Net MVC app using jqGrid.  Can I send the Model that is used to populate a lot of my ui controls(checkboxes, radio buttons, etc) to the server(controler action  method).  I would like to send this Model to the server instead of reading ui control by ui control.  Can this be done?

```
  var myGrid = jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
                    url: '/Data/GridData/',
                    datatype: 'json',
                    mtype: 'POST',
                    colNames: ['Year', 'Overall %'],
                    colModel: [
                                            { name: 'Year', index: 'Year', width: 80, align: 'center' },

                                            { name: 'overallHarvestPercent', index: 'overallHarvestPercent', width: 80, align: 'center'}],

                    postData: { contactId: jQuery('#contactId').val() },
                    pager: jQuery('#pager'),
                    rowNum: 10,
                    rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
                    sortname: 'id',
                    sortorder: "desc",
                    viewrecords: true,
                    imgpath: '',
                    caption: 'Harvest Data Results'
                });
```

Comment: Model exists only on server, so what you really need to do?

Comment: Do you mean to send more controls from the form instead of usage of `contactId: jQuery('#contactId').val()` inside of `postData`?

Comment: Oleg...yes, that is what I mean. So, I have 8 different sets of radio buttons and checkboxes as filter data. Then the user clicks the Submit button, I would like the View Model that I use to populate default values, to then be sent to the server method as a parameter.

Comment: Have you tried specifying your Model as the data type for the Controller Action's Parameter? i.e. public ActionResult(MyModel model)..

Comment: I think Jed just help answer...I put this in my jqGrid code:   postData: { species: jQuery('#contactId').val() },  ContactId is a hidden field that has my Model. Then I added the parameter and parameter type to my controler action method. That seems to work. Jed, put your info in an 'Answer' so I can select it as answered so you get credit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify your Model as the data type for the Controller Action's Parameter.

```
public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
{
 // Do stuff 
}
```